# Fragment does not pop out from backstack?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I have three fragment A, B and C

[image]
This is the path : A -> B -> C : **A** go to **B** and **B** go to **C**

When I go back from the fragment C , I want to go to the fragment A.

- A <- C :  **C** go back to the root fragment **A**
- A <- B :  **B** go back to the root fragment **A**

But My problem is when I pressed back in the fragment C , I get this behviour : It seems that the fragment C is not cleared from the backstack :  [image]

As for my code , this is the method of the replaceFragment :

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean withBackStack) {
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    String fragmentTag = fragment.getClass().getName();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, fragmentTag);
    if (withBackStack)
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragmentTag);
    try {
        fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

First I called  `replaceFragment(new AFragment(), false);` in the `MainActivity` , Then in the **Fragment A** when I clicked in the button, I called   `mListener.replaceFragment(new BFragment(), true);`
 Finally , in the **Fragment B** when I clicked the button , I called `mListener.replaceFragment(new CFragment(), false);`

Does anyone have an explanation for this behaviour ? The last fragment C shouldn't be cleared when I click backpressed ?

[Here](https://github.com/imen-nmn/BackStackExample) , you will find the whole example.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: share your xml file.

Comment: In the xml file , I just add a simple textview in fragment and a frameLayout in the activity. Anyway , this is the link of the example: https://github.com/imen-nmn/BackStackExample

Comment: i check your code, i have missed to set background color in your fragment xml file.that's why its overlapping.

Comment: set the background color to parent view of your fragment A, B ,C, you will never face this problem again

Comment: Adding color will not remove fragments from backstack. You need to call add (instead of replace ) for first fragment and then use replace for all other fragments. OnBack press use code getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

Comment: @RadheshyamSingh Unfortunally , this does not work . Also, also I want to found a solution without modifying the default behavior of onBackPressed() Because I could add another fragments in the scenario

Comment: You have to override backpressed unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not adding fragC to the backstack when backpressed wont pop the stored transaction it is not removed.instead here you have to remove the fragment by overriding backpress.Overiride backpress and check for the fragC and remove it and then call the pospstack to pop back the stored transaction.

Also store the instance of fragment as global to check if the fragment if fragC.

```
private Fragment mFragment;
```

Inside you method store the instance

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mFragment.getClass().getName());
        if (fragment != null && fragment.getClass().getName().equalsIgnoreCase(CFragment.class.getName())) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mFragment).commit();
        }
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is right that when I go back from C , I redirect me to A . But when I go back from B , It stucks in B. 
Also, I'm searching an explanation, why C is not cleared from backstack in my example ?

Comment: sorry that was a slight mistake..see the updated code

Comment: You are not adding C to backstack..Hence it wont be removed onBackpress.The fragment that are added to backstack are only the ones that will be cleared when the back is pressed

Comment: Go through the difference between add,replace and addstacktobackstack.Then you will clearly understand it.Hope my answer helps you:)

Comment: Thanks for the answer . It inspired me for a general solution that I will post it .

Comment: Your welcome.You can override backpress but should not mess with the android system backpress method thatz it.If you are adding more fragment you can check and remove fragment in backpress.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of @Anonymous,  I found a general solution for this problem  :

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Fragment currentFragment= getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame);
        super.onBackPressed();

        if(currentFragment!=null && currentFragment.isVisible()) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(currentFragment).commit();
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(currentFragment.getTag(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        }

    }
```